# Can not get bibliography working in Kile

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Using Kile on linux I'm trying to write an article in elsevier and include bibliography:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,preprint,12pt,final,1p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}

  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
  \bibliography{myrefs}
  % this shows references stored in the myrefs.bib file
  \nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

The `myrefs.bib` file has this content:

```
@ARTICLE{Zurek,
   AUTHOR  = {Zurek, R. W. and Martin, L. J.},
   TITLE   = {Interannual Variability of planet-encircling dust activity on {M}ars},  
   YEAR    = {1993},
   JOURNAL = jgr,
   VOLUME  = {98},
   NUMBER  = {E2},
   PAGES   = {3247--3259}
}
```

Then I press `PdfLaTex` (compiled fine), `BibTex` (finished with exit code 2), so it is not clear what is wrong. Could you please help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: I tried your example and it works well.

Comment: Could you provide more details on the errors messages you get from BibTeX?

Comment: This is the only error message I get:
[BibTex]: finished with exit code 2.

Comment: Please show us the contents of the file `blg`.

Comment: Its contents start with:
`This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (Web2C 7.5.6)
The top-level auxiliary file: sophie.aux
I couldn't open style file elsarticle-num.bst
---line 31 of file sophie.aux
 : \bibstyle{elsarticle-num
 :                         }`

Comment: Hmm, seems this file is not reachable. Strange.

Comment: What happens if you type `kpsewhich elsarticle-num.bst`? I get `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/elsarticle/elsarticle-num.bst`

Comment: Stupid, I can not answer my own question, so writing here: 
I downloaded [missed file][1] and put it in the folder where my `sophie.tex` is. Now is working. To be more subtle, I guess I should put it in the /usr/...latex folder (do not remember full path).

  [1]: http://cdn.elsevier.com/assets/file/0006/109365/elsarticle-num.bst

Comment: One hint: The entry journal accept a string and so you need braces: `journal = {jgr}`

Comment: I'm sorry, where I need to put it and what jgr means? Jaguar? :)

Comment: It's your example ;-)

Comment: Aaa, I did not even notice because took it from the web. Alright, thank you. Now this question can be removed :)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>The OP doesn't have enough reputation to answer her question, so I provide this CW</sub>

The log file of BibTeX compiling shows:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (Web2C 7.5.6) 
The top-level auxiliary file: sophie.aux 
I couldn't open style file elsarticle-num.bst ---
line 31 of file sophie.aux : \bibstyle{elsarticle-num : }
```

---

I downloaded [missed file](http://cdn.elsevier.com/assets/file/0006/109365/elsarticle-num.bst) and put it in the folder where my `sophie.tex` is. Now is working. To be more subtle, I guess I should put it in the `/usr/...latex` folder (do not remember full path).

---

However the missed file is part of TeX Live and should be available via `tlmgr`: [CTAN `elsarticle-num`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle)